# Finding the smallest positive integer $N$ such that there are $25$ integers $x$ with $2 \leq \frac{N}{x} \leq 5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Find the smallest positive integer $N$ such that there are exactly $25$ integers $x$ satisfying $2 \leq \frac{N}{x} \leq 5$.

Comment: If you want the **least** such integer $N$, the answer will be negative.  **Smallest** is
somewhat ambiguous when applied to integers that can be negative.

Comment: positive integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x > 0$, $2 \le N/x \le 5$ iff $\frac{N}{5}  \le x \le \frac{N}{2}$.  Thus you need
$\lfloor N/2 \rfloor - \lceil N/5 \rceil = 24$.  If $N = 10 q + r$, $r \in [0,1,\ldots,9]$, 
$$ \lfloor N/2 \rfloor -  \lceil N/5 \rceil  = 3 q +  \lfloor r/2 \rfloor -  \lceil r/5 \rceil$$
For $r = 0,1,\ldots,9$, $ \lfloor r/2 \rfloor -  \lceil r/5 \rceil = 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2$.  We need a value divisible by $3$ since $24$ and $3q$ are divisible by $3$, so $r = 0, 2$ or $3$; $q = 24/3 = 8$, and thus $N$ is either $80$, $82$ or $83$.

Answer (score 4):

$x$ ranges from $N/5$ through $N/2$ (ignoring the breakage) so $N/2-N/5+1=25$ so $N=80$ and a check shows $x$ goes $16$ through $40$